# To put two level of data in one tableau worksheet and aggregate them

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I'm building up a supervisor scorecard on Tableau. Basically, there're two parts impacted on supervisor's score. One is supervisor's own performance, eg. there own's lateness. And the other part was their reporting employees' performance, eg. their employees' absenteesim. 
My expectation is aggregating all the criteria in dashbaord, and filter supervisor's ID get his scorecard data. Here is a sample of the raw data:
[image] 
So from the data we can know that for each CSR, they all have their supervisor, and for a supervisor, their reporting supervisor(which should be a manager) is blank.

So I created 3 calculation filed. One is called SUP_ID, and here's the code:

```
IF  ISNULL([SupervisorID]) THEN [EmployeeID]
ELSE [SupervisorID]
END
```

Another calculation filed is called SUP_Flag, the code is :

```
[EmployeeID]=[SupervisorID____OLD]
```

The last one called SupervisorID___OLD], the code is:

```
IF [ROLE] = 'Supervisor' THEN [EmployeeID]
ELSE NULL
END
```

With these three calculation field, i'm able to use SUP_ID to filter all the information I want in each worksheet. When I want each supervisor's belonging employee's performance, I'll just use SUP_ID as filter. If I want each supervisor's own performance, I use SUP_ID as well as SUP_Flag to give me the information, and it works very well.

Everything above was done by separate worksheet.

Now my problem is:
There's a field that i need to put is called supervisor's final score, and it combines with both employee's performance score and supervisor's own performance score together in one filed. These two score are both in previous seperate worksheet. I'm thinking to use LOD to aggregate them, but it doesn't work as my expectation.

Here's what i wrote:
Final_Score_Part1(Sup's performance)

```
{FIXED [SUP_ID],[Supe Flag]: ([EVALUATION SC]*1* 0.2)}
```

Final_Socre_Part2(Employee's performance)

```
{FIXED [SUP_ID],[Supe Flag]:  ((([LOST TIME %] * 0.6) + ([ATTENDENCE_SC]*0.2) + ([PUNCTUALITY_SC]*0.2)) * 0.5 )}
```

Final_Score:

```
Final_Score_Part1 + Final_Socre_Part2
```

Here's the screenshot that Tableau gave me.
[image]
(I've crossed out Supervisor's name)
So you can see that the part1 score was based on Sup_Flag = True, and part2 socre is based on SUp_Flag = Null, so when i aggregate them, it still won't give me the correct score.

Can somebody help me with this? I'll be so apprecaited for your help.

Thanks

Hi @Phani,
As i couldn't upload an image in comment, i've posted the new image here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqoVl.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Final_Score_Part1(Sup's performance): include the condition 
IF [ROLE] = 'Supervisor' THEN calculate the score[]
ELSE NULL
END

The same condition need to be used in Final_Socre_Part2(Employee's performance).

Comment: Hi @phani, thank you for your comment. However, it doesn't work. There're two figuers in part 2 are not correct. For 4252, the part 2 score should be 0.32 ,and for 7197, the part 2 score should be 0.32 as well, but in the report, it gave me 0.34 and 0.265. Do you happen to know where this two figuers might come from where? Everything else is correct.